# xpath expression to check multiple values

Tags: xml, xpath, expression, contains

This is my xpath expression:

countries.xpath=//*[local-name()='CountryIdentifier']/text()='1067' or //*[local-name()='CountryIdentifier']/text()='874' or //*[local-name()='CountryIdentifier']/text()='994'   .............

like i have 50 countries to add in the above expression so it will be quite big xpath expression

Is there any way to use "contains method" or to reduce the size of the expression like

eg:
 countries.xpath=//*[local-name()='CountryIdentifier']/text()=[1067,874,994,..]

Comment: Could you shoe the XML example? I believe it will be possible to achieve what you need.

Comment: <idp-prof:Header>
                  <idp-com:DUNSNumber contextRef="mr" unitRef="pure">988683686</idp-com:DUNSNumber>
                  <idp-com:CountryIdentifier contextRef="mr" unitRef="pure">956</idp-com:CountryIdentifier>
               </idp-prof:Header>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 you can write

```
//*:CountryIdentifier[.=(1067,874,994,..)]
```

In 1.0 you can write

```
//*[local-name()='CountryIdentifier'][.=1067 or .=874 or .=994 ...]
```

Try to avoid using text(): you don't want the text nodes, you want the string value of the element. Using text() makes your expression less robust, eg. it fails if there are comments or if the elements you are selecting have internal markup. And in an expression like this, it makes your code much more long-winded.

Comment: Thanks Much Michael Kay!

Comment: @Michael Kay is there any way for xPath 2.0 where you can use 'contains' function for multiple values? f.x. contains('cd', ('abcd','dfgh','zxcd') ) ?

Comment: The general solution is `some $s in ('abcd', 'xyz', pqr') satisfies contains(cd, $s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your solution and if it does not work read below.

```
//CountryIdentifier[text()='1067' or text()='874' or text()='994']
```

Let's assume that your XML looks like this:

```
<root>
    <Countries>
        <CountryIdentifier id="2">12</actor>
        <CountryIdentifier id="3">13</actor>
        <CountryIdentifier id="4">14</actor>
    </Countries>
</root>
```

In order to get specific countries:

**by ID:**

```
/root/Countries/CountryIdentifier[@id='2' or @id='4']
```

**by node value**

```
/root/Countries/CountryIdentifier[text()='12' or text()='14']
```

Comment: Thanks Dmytro,
//CountryIdentifier[text()='1067' or text()='874' or text()='994']
or shall i try with adding * in ur answer?
//*CountryIdentifier[text()='1067' or text()='874' or text()='994']

Comment: @Danny I did not get your question. Have you tried my solutions?
I do not see why would you need to use *, try just //CountryIdentifier

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have hundred `Country Identifier`, At that time you cant use      `//CountryIdentifier[text()='17' or text()='46' or text()='94'or....]`for hundred values.

Follow the below steps..

***When you want to check for large data, you can you following code***

```
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                List<WebElement> ab =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[local-name()='CountryIdentifier']"));
                for(int i=0;i<ab.size();i++)
                {
                    set.add(ab.get(i).getText());   
                }
                System.out.println(set);
                for(String a:set)
                {
                    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("Pass ur text here to verify whether it is present in the set"))
                        System.out.println("present in UI");
                }
```

First I'm saving all `Country Identifier` text in `Set<String>`

In this if statement you can pass your own text and verify whether it is present in the retrieved set.

```
if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("Pass ur text here to verify whether it is present in the set"))
                            System.out.println("present in UI");
                    }
```

Comment: deepak i need using xpath expression . am using this expression in a property file

Comment: yes @danny i can understand but if your data is large means, you can't be writing large Xpath like "//CountryIdentifier[text()='17' or text()='46' or text()='94'or....] ". And its time consuming.